# AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'printHam_btn'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtgui

I'm started learning QtDesigner (Python) with Qt 4.8.6 and I follow this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLqrzLIIW2E

but it showing me sometimes error in title sometimes AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'printHam_btn'. Can someone please tell me what i have to do or fix my code.

Thanks!

I know that this problem is already post in this forum but I can't find out what I have to do in my case.

**CODE:**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.print_ham = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.print_ham.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("print_ham"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.print_ham)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Super ham", None))
        self.print_ham.setText(_translate("Form", "print ham", None))
        self.printHam_btn.clicked.connect(self.printHam)

    def printHam(self):
        print('Ham!')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Ui_Form()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The title and the first paragraph mention different errors. There is not any QPaintDevice in the code you posted. Are you sure you wrote the correct title for this question?

Comment: OK, well, the title does not seem to make sense based on the code provided, given that the first thing the main does is to create an application instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
self.printHam_btn.clicked.connect(self.printHam)
```

You call your QPushButton instance differently, so you would need to change this line to:

```
self.print_ham.clicked.connect(self.printHam)
```